# Setup SRV DNS records for mail server

Tags: dns

I am setting up my DNS zone to build a complete server on a VPS.

My actual issue is about setting up the SRV fields for my mail server such as : `_autodiscover._tcp`, `_imaps._tcp`, `_pop3s._tcp` and `_submission._tcp`.

These are the fields present by default in my DNS zone at my VPS provider, which I believe are useful for the mail clients to retrieve the `imap`, `pop3` and `smtp` name server of the mail server.

My first idea was to put :

```
_autodiscover._tcp   3600 IN SRV    0 0 443 ? (I have no idea for this one)
_imaps._tcp          3600 IN SRV    0 0 993 imap.mydomain.com
_pop3s._tcp          3600 IN SRV    0 0 995 pop3.mydomain.com
_submission._tcp     3600 IN SRV    0 0 465 smtp.mydomain.com
```

But my host provider (which is OVH for the french who know it) give me a **warning**

```
zone mydomain.com/IN: _imaps._tcp.mydomain.com/SRV 'imap.mydomain.com' is a CNAME (illegal)
```

when I do this, **because** `imap.mydomain.com` and `smtp.mydomain.com` are **already registered as `CNAME` fields**.

```
imap                 3600 IN CNAME  mail.mydomain.com.
pop3                 3600 IN CNAME  mail.mydomain.com.
smtp                 3600 IN CNAME  mail.mydomain.com.
```

For me, doing it that way looks normal, because I can not specify subdomains in SRV records that I did not declare on my DNS zone and I really wanted to make it fancy using `imap.mydomain.com`, `pop3.mydomain.com` and `smtp.mydomain.com`.

So what is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: what exactly does the warning say?

Comment: @mdeora updated

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/765743/published-srv-records-pointing-to-cname-alias-in-violation-of-rfc-2782 - read this.

Comment: @mdeora So I just have to remove my `CNAME` records of `imap`, `pop3` and `smtp` and use it as `A` records ?

Comment: yes give it a try.

Comment: @mdeora do you know if these are the right records for Thunderbird autoconfig ?